# How to save state in an Erlang process?

Tags: erlang

I am learning Erlang and trying to figure out how I can, and should, save state inside a process.

For example, I am trying to write a program that given a list of numbers in a file, tells me whether a number appears in that file. My approach is to uses two processes

- **cache** which reads the content of the file into a set, then waits for numbers to check, and then replies whether they appear in the set.

  ```
  is_member_loop(Data_file) ->
      Numbers = read_numbers(Data_file),
      receive
          {From, Number} ->
              From ! {self(), lists:member(Number, Numbers)},
              is_member_loop(Data_file)
      end.
  ```
- **client** which sends numbers to *cache* and waits for the `true` or `false` response.

  ```
  check_number(Number) ->
      NumbersPid ! {self(), Number},
      receive
          {NumbersPid, Is_member} ->
              Is_member
      end.
  ```

This approach is obviously naive since the file is read for every request. However, I am quite new at Erlang and it is unclear to me what would be the preferred way of keeping state between different requests.

Should I be using the process dictionary? Is there a different mechanism I am not aware of for that sort of process state?

### Update

The most obvious solution, as suggested by *user601836*, is to pass the set of numbers as a param to `is_member_loop` instead of the filename. It seems to be a common idiom in Erlang and there is a good example in the fantastic online book [Learn you some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/more-on-multiprocessing#state-your-state).

I think, however, that the question still holds for more complex state that I'd want to preserve in my process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple solution, you can pass to your function `is_member_loop(Data_file)` the list of numbers rather then the file name.

The best solution when you deal with a state consists in using a gen_server. To learn more you should take a look at [records](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html) and [gen_server behaviour](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) ([this](http://spawnlink.com/articles/an-introduction-to-gen_server-erlybank/index.html) may also be useful).

In practice:

1) start with a module (yourmodule.erl) based on gen_server behaviour
2) read your file in the init function of the gen_server and pass it as state field:

```
init([]) ->
    Numbers = read_numbers(Data_file),
{ok, #state{numbers=Numbers}}.
```

3) write a function which will be used to trigger a call to the gen_server

```
check_number(Number) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {check_number, Number}).
```

4) write the code in order to handle messages triggered from your function

```
handle_call({check_number, Number}, _From, #state{numbers=Numbers} = State) ->
    Reply = lists:member(Number, Numbers)},
{reply, Reply, State};

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
{reply, Reply, State}.
```

5) export from yourmodule.erl function `check_number`

```
-export([check_number/1]).
```

Two things to be explained about point 4:

a) we extract values inside the record State using pattern matching

b) As you may see I left the generic handle call, otherwise your gen_server will fail due to wrong pattern matching whenever a message different from {check_number, Number} is received

Note: if you are new to erlang, don't use process dictionary

Comment: I almost feel stupid not to have thought myself about passing the list itself as an argument instead of the file name. I was thinking about the process dictionary because in [Programming Erlang](http://pragprog.com/book/jaerlang/programming-erlang), Joe Armstrong uses it in one of his examples. I read online that it was a discouraged practice though, hence my question. Finally, I am a newbie and haven't reached the OTP part yet but the `gen_server` seems like the better approach indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how idiomatic this is, since I'm not exactly an Erlang pro yet, but I'd handle this by using [ETS](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html). Basically,

```
read_numbers_to_ets(DataFile) ->
    Table = ets:new(numbers, [ordered_set]),
    insert_numbers(Table, DataFile),
    Table.

insert_numbers(Table, DataFile) ->
    case read_next_number(DataFile) of
    eof -> ok;
    Num -> ets:insert(numbers, {Num})
    end.
```

you could then define your `is_member` as

```
is_member(TableId, Number) ->
    case ets:match(TableId, {Number}) of
    [] -> false; %% no match from ets
    [[]] -> true %% ets found the number you're looking for in that table
    end.
```

Instead of taking a `Data_file`, your `is_member_loop` would take the id of the table to do a lookup on.

Comment: ets is a solution, but you must be careful since if the owner process crashes your ets table will be lost as well.